# ¿Cómo imprimir datos de un input en el mismo lugar? PHP

Tags: php, javascript, imprimir

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo una página la cual muestra datos de mi base de datos y adicional, cuenta con cajas de texto (`input type = "text"`), las cajas de texto no están relacionadas con la base de datos, ya que no se requiere almacenar información en ellas, pero si requiero que al escribir en estas, a la hora de imprimir se muestre en el PDF (este es generado por la opción "Imprimir..." de Google Chrome).

Este es un fragmento del código, donde específicamente se encuentra las cajas de texto y en donde ocupo que se muestren los datos:

```
<div>
  <table class= "table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana; width: 650px"
        for="subscribeNews">Did this business file 1099Misc form this fiscal year?</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label
        for="subscribeNews1"><input type="text" id="subscribeNews1" name="subscribe1"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana; width: 650px"
        for="subscribeNews">If the answer is "YES". Please, indicate the date the forms were printed.</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="subscribeNews2" name="subscribe2" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana; width: 650px"
        for="subscribeNews">Did this business pay dividends during this fiscal year?</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="subscribeNews3" name="subscribe3" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana; width: 650px"
        for="subscribeNews">If the answer is "YES". Please, indicate the date the forms were printed.</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="subscribeNews4" name="subscribe4" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana; width: 650px"
        for="subscribeNews">Did this business pay distributions during this fiscal year?</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="subscribeNews5" name="subscribe5" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana; width: 650px"
        for="subscribeNews">Is this the first or last business' return?</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="subscribeNews6" name="subscribe6" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana; width: 650px"
        for="subscribeNews">If the answer is "First Return". Please, indicate operations start date.</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="subscribeNews7" name="subscribe7" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana; width: 650px"
        for="subscribeNews">Did this business make estimated federal payments?</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="subscribeNews8" name="subscribe8" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div>
    <label
    style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana; width: 650px"
    for="subscribeNews">If the answer is "YES".Please, fill the following gaps:</label>
  </div>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana;  text-align: center; width: 200px"
        >Number of payments</th>
        <th
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana;  text-align: center; width: 200px"
        >Date of the payment</th>
        <th
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana;  text-align: center; width: 200px"
        >Amount paid</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana;  text-align: center; width: 200px"
        >First payment</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="datepayment1" name="datepayment1" value=" ">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="amountpaid1" name="amountpaid1" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana;  text-align: center; width: 200px"
        >Second payment</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="datepayment2" name="datepayment2" value=" ">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="amountpaid2" name="amountpaid2" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana;  text-align: center; width: 200px"
        >Third payment</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="datepayment3" name="datepayment3" value=" ">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="amountpaid3" name="amountpaid3" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana;  text-align: center; width: 200px"
        >Fourth payment</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="datepayment4" name="datepayment4" value=" ">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="amountpaid4" name="amountpaid4" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <table class = "table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana; width: 650px"
        for="subscribeNews">Did this business make estimated state payments?</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="subscribeNews9" name="subscribe9" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <label
  style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana; width: 650px"
  for="subscribeNews">If the answer is "YES".Please, fill the following gaps:</label>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana;  text-align: center; width: 200px"
        >Number of payments</th>
        <th
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana;  text-align: center; width: 200px"
        >Date of the payment</th>
        <th
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana;  text-align: center; width: 200px"
        >Amount paid</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana;  text-align: center; width: 200px"
        >First payment</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="datepayment5" name="datepayment5" value=" ">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="amountpaid5" name="amountpaid5" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana;  text-align: center; width: 200px"
        >Second payment</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="datepayment6" name="datepayment6" value=" ">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="amountpaid6" name="amountpaid6" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana;  text-align: center; width: 200px"
        >Third payment</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="datepayment7" name="datepayment7" value=" ">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="amountpaid7" name="amountpaid7" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p
        style="font-size: 14px ;font-family: verdana;  text-align: center; width: 200px"
        >Fourth payment</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="datepayment8" name="datepayment8" value=" ">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="amountpaid8" name="amountpaid8" value=" ">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<br><br>
<div>
  <p style="font-size: 16px ;font-family: verdana"><b>Notes:</b></p>

  <hr style="height: 250px; border-color: black">

</div>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:imprSelec('seleccion')" >Print</a>
</div>


<script language="Javascript">
  function imprSelec(nombre) {
    var ficha = document.getElementById(nombre);
    var ventimp = window.open(' ', 'popimpr');
    ventimp.document.write( ficha.innerHTML );
    ventimp.document.close();
    ventimp.print( );
    ventimp.close();
  }
</script>
```

Espero puedan entenderlo, me dieron el código para continuar con él, por lo que me disculpo por la falta de formato.

Les agradecería demasiado su apoyo.

Comment: lo que quieres es que imprima los valores en campos para después esos valores los cambien en el pdf?

Comment: No, los valores ya deben quedar impresos y no tengan que cambiar nada en el pdf

Comment: creo no estoy entendiendo, que es exactamente lo que no te funciona?

Comment: Ok, me explico: Los usuarios llenan las cajas de texto (el input), (no es un formulario, no se guarda en ninguna tabla) cuando presionan el botón "Print" se abre la opción imprimir de google (eso está bien) pero lo que llenaron en las cajas de texto no se ve a la hora de generar el pdf y solo editando el pdf es como lo vuelven a llenar, yo quiero que no editen el pdf, que se almacene lo que ingresan en el input y al imprimir aparezca ahí mismo

Comment: con que generas el pdf?

Comment: Con la opción Imprimir del navegador y se guarda como pdf, únicamente (podría decirse que se imprime la página web)

Answer (score 0):

Marisol Rodríguez te recomiendo que hagas el ejemplo para poder ejecutarlo o poner el codigo completo para poder entender mejor tu pregunta.

Cuando formulas la pregunta te aparece el cuerpo en los botones de arriba te aparece fragmento javascript le das click y te da las opciones para insertar código html, javascript, css y el resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui encontraras un poco de información que puede ser de ayuda
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Gracias! No había querido añadir el código completo debido a que es muy amplio y la parte en la que requiero que haga la acción es específicamente esa parte, pero si es necesario, lo agrego todo.